# Is there any way to define a mapping to allow a subset of object keys AND let elastic determine the types dynamically?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to avoid field explosion when logging HTTP requests. I would like to whitelist the request headers that will be indexed (or otherwise count toward the total field limit). For each whitelisted header, I would like to index as text and keyword.

Currently, I have the following test mapping which works fine:

```
PUT /test-index/_mapping
{
  "dynamic": "false",
  "properties": {
    "req": {
      "dynamic": true,
      "properties": {
        "headers": {
          "dynamic": false,
          "properties": {
            "accept": { "type": "text", "fields": { "keyword": { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } } },
            "content-type": { "type": "text", "fields": { "keyword": { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } } }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I want to extend this in order to whitelist dozens of headers. Is there any way to accomplish this without having to repeat the `type` and `fields` definitions for each property? I have explored using dynamic templates but I cannot seem to find a way to make them work for this use case.

My HTTP request logs will also contain an object for querystring values and I would like to whitelist a subset of the properties on that object as well. The key difference when compared to the headers object is that the querystring values will not all have the same type, so I would like elasticsearch to do its dynamic thing on those values.

Edit: the following is an attempt to use dynamic_templates to allow-list the headers. The search at the end returns no hits.

```
DELETE test-index
PUT test-index
PUT test-index/_mapping
{
  "dynamic_templates": [
    {
      "allow-headers": {
        "match": ["req.headers.user-agent", "req.headers.sec-*"],
        "mapping": {
          "type": "text", 
          "fields": { 
            "keyword": { 
              "type": "keyword", 
              "ignore_above": 256 
            } 
          } 
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "dynamic": false,
  "properties": {
    "req": {
      "dynamic": true,
      "properties": {
        "headers": {
          "dynamic": false,
          "type": "object"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test-index/_doc
{
  "req": {
    "foo": "bar",
    "headers": {
      "user-agent": "test",
      "sec-foo": "test",
      "do-not-index-me": "test"
    }
  }
}

GET /test-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "req.headers.user-agent": "test"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Dynamic templates is the way to go. Using `match` you can specify the name patterns you want to map. If the header names do not share any common patterns, you might have to specify multiple `match` rules to capture them all. However, if you know exactly the set of headers you want to map, you might as well declare them explicitly in your mapping. Same goes for the query string object.

Comment: I like the idea of using dynamic templates because it seems like it would give a more succinct and DRY mapping. Plus it would be good to be able to match say any header starting with a certain prefix. No problem adding multiple match patterns. I just wasn't able to make that work. Kept getting either all the headers indexed or none of them. I will edit my question with more details.

Comment: Sure, and add the dynamic template you were using and which didn't work

Comment: @Val I added the dynamic template. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is indeed having `"dynamic": false` in `req.headers` as that will prevent any dynamic field creation, even when specified via dynamic templates. I'm afraid you'll need to whitelist your headers inside `req.headers`, which is a good thing when thinking in terms of maintainability for your future colleagues ;-)